# Show I/O rates of all processes in htop?

Tags: linux, debian, monitoring, htop

[`htop` 3.2.2](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/htop) running as a regular user only shows I/O rates (`IO_RATE`/`IO_READ_RATE`/`IO_WRITE_RATE`) for *some* processes and "N/A" for others.

Running as root shows I/O for all processes.

How can I configure htop show I/O rates for *all* processes while running as a regular user?

Answer (score 0):

`htop` tries to read the `/proc/pid/io` file for each process to get I/O statistics.

Near the end of the `/proc/pid/io` section of [`proc(5)`](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/manpages/proc.5.en.html) we have:

> Permission to access this file is governed by a ptrace access mode `PTRACE_MODE_READ_FSCREDS` check; see ptrace(2).

General `ptrace()` permissions can be granted with [`CAP_SYS_PTRACE`](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/manpages/capabilities.7.en.html#CAP_SYS_PTRACE) but we also need [`CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH`](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/manpages/capabilities.7.en.html#CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH) to bypass the file-read permission checks done by [the `ptrace()` access algorithm](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/manpages-dev/ptrace.2.en.html#Ptrace_access_mode_checking).

[`setcap(8)`](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/libcap2-bin/setcap.8.en.html) can be used to set both capabilities on the `htop` executable:

```
sudo setcap 'cap_sys_ptrace=ep cap_dac_read_search=ep' /usr/bin/htop
```

The cap bits can be verified with:

```
sudo getcap /usr/bin/htop
```

...or reset all together:

```
sudo setcap '' /usr/bin/htop
```